# Implementing Bulk/Batch Insert using ADO Command Object

Tags: c++, oledb, ado, bulkinsert

So I'm trying to implement Batch insert functionality using ADO's Command object.

I know I could do this using ADO's Recordset object as follows..

```
// Open table
_RecordsetPtr RecSet = NULL;
RecSet.CreateInstance(__uuidof(Recordset));
RecSet->Open("MY_TABLE", MY_CONNECTION_STRING, adOpenKeyset, adLockBatchOptimistic, adCmdTable);

// Add Rows to Batch
for (int i=0; i<10000; i++) {
    RectSet->AddNew(SOME_OBJECT);
}

// Execute batch
RecSet->UpdateBatch(adAffectAll);
```

I've hided most of the details,, but this works fine.

The only problem with this approach,,, is that it is EXTREMELY slow..

To insert 10,000 records, it took almost **60 seconds**.

I've found out that ADO's Command executes commands way faster than the Recordset object..

This is how I normally insert 10,000 records using the Command object:

```
_CommandPtr CommPtr;
CommPtr.CreateInstance(__uuidof(Command));
CommPtr->CommandType = adCmdText;
CommPtr->CommandText = L"insert into aggrdb..sequence_number values (999999)";

for (int i=0; i<NUM_RECORDS; i++) {
    CommPtr->Execute(NULL, NULL, adExecuteNoRecords);
}
```

Surprisingly this same operation took about **24 seconds** to execute (vs 60 seconds using Recordset object)..

What I want now is to implement Batch Insert functionality using this Command object..

The code I wrote above inserts records one by one,, instead of first adding to a batch so that we need to only execute a single batch of operations..

Looking at ADO Documentation,, I have no clue about how this could be done..
([Documentation Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677502%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

Is this even possible? Any thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The batch code looks OK. You can try to change the batch size to see if it will be any difference.

```
ADO::PropertyPtr p1 = pRecordset->Properties->GetItem("Batch Size");
```

p1->Value = 100;

Also, please set the CursorLocation,

```
pRecordset->CursorLocation = ADO::adUseClient;
```

I think you are working on your local database, trying to connect to a remote database to see the difference.